# How to take integer dynamic 2d-array as input in python(Online IDE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, input, dynamic

I want to take a 2d array of free size as user input in python in an online compiler where the number of rows and columns are not defined.

```
For example if the input is :

1 2 3 4
5 6 7
8 9
10
11 12 13 14 15

I want to store it like [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9],[10],[11,12,13,14,15]]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know that online IDE throws an EOF error when there are excess input statments in code but no input given considering this We can take dynamic input in online IDE.

```py
matrix = []
while True:
    try:
        matrix.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
    except:
        break
```

You can do it by knowing about carry return too at the end of every new line you will have carry return ('\r') except the last line

```py
matrix = []
while True:
    row = input()
    matrix.append(row.strip())
    print(row)
    if row[-1] != '\r':
        break
```